# Multiple integration questions and my attempt

Tags: multivariable-calculus

P1: Find volume of portion of sphere centered at $(0,a,0)$ with radius $a$,  between planes $y=0$ and $y=a$ .

I changed to spherical coordinates and I calculated volume in 1st quadrant and multiplied by 4 to  get required volume. The limits for $\theta$ and $\phi$ are $0$ to $\pi/2$ and for $\rho$ are $0$ to $2\sin\theta \sin \phi$, but I couldn't get correct and and is double than what it is. Where am I wrong ? Can please someone help me figure out .

P2: 
Find volume of portion of sphere which is inside right circular cone having its vertex at origin and making angle alpha with positive z axis ..
in this q i dont know bounds..can someone help me with bounds only and explanation of them

P3: Find volume of solid which is below plane z=2x+3 and in xy plane bounded by $y^{2}=x$ , $x=0$ , $x=2$ ..i cant figure out region to integrate over in xy plane

Comment: Where's the "21" from in your bounds for $\rho$?

Comment: @GFauxPas .its a typo .its 2 instead

Comment: I see. And what do you mean by planes $y = 0$ and $y = a$? Those are lines. But in any event, please show us what integrand you tried.

Comment: @GFauxPas Integrand is 1 anyway

Comment: Not quite: You need to put in the Jacobian. Just making sure that wasn't the source of the mistake!

Comment: @GFauxPas oh sorry i used jacobian ofcourse .ididnt meant to say that

Comment: P1. I do not think you need an integral to solve it. The plane $y=a$ (which is parallel to the $xz$-plane and goes through the center $(0,a,0)$ of the sphere, clearly at the same time perpendicular to the $y$-axis at $(0,a,0)$) cuts the given sphere into two semi-spheres. The plane $y=0$ only touches the sphere at the origin and does not cut anything from it. The volume of a sphere with radius $a$, is $\frac43\pi a^3$, so then the volume of the semi-sphere is $\frac23\pi a^3$. I do not quite follow your other statements, e.g. in P3 what do you mean by y^=x ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For part 1, you have correctly determined that the spherical coordinates of
a point on the sphere are $2a \sin \phi \sin \theta.$
(You don't write the factor of $a$ but I assume you are scaling the region down
by that factor and that you scale up your result appropriately.)

The problem is that you are now computing the entire volume of the sphere,
whereas you are only supposed to find the volume of the hemisphere between
the planes $y=0$ and $y=a.$
For chords of the sphere that pass through the disk $x^2 + z^2 \leq a^2$ in the
plane $y = a,$ you are integrating over the whole length of the chord whereas
you really should integrate only over the part for which $y \leq a.$

If you're going to do this with spherical coordinates around the $z$-axis,
it means splitting your region of integration in two parts in a somewhat
complicated way.
For $\theta$ such that $cos^2\theta \geq \frac{1-2\cos^2\phi}{2\sin^2\phi}$
(if I've done the calculation correctly--you should check this), you can integrate
over the sphere as you are doing. But for other $\theta$ you want to be integrating
over a right circular cone whose base is in the plane $y=a.$
For that region, the range of $\rho$ is from $\rho = 0$ to
$\rho = \frac{a}{\sin\phi\sin\theta}.$

This is much easier if you take spherical coordinates around the $y$-axis
instead of the $z$-axis.
If $\phi$ is measured from the $y$-axis then $\theta$ no longer appears in
the equation of the sphere; $\rho$ is bounded by the plane $y=a$
whenever $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac\pi4,$ and $\rho$ is bounded by the surface
of the sphere for $\frac\pi4 \leq \phi \leq \frac\pi2.$
Presumably there is a point to this exercise
other than just getting the answer (since the answer is so easy to get without
doing any integration at all!), so you'll have to decide how to do it,
but if "spherical coordinates" were specified without specifying the axis,
perhaps this is an acceptable simplification.  (Perhaps the point is to understand
the difference it makes to choose an appropriate axis for the spherical coordinates,
in which case the $y$-axis is probably the intended choice!)

For part 2, the cone consists simply of all points for which $\phi=\alpha.$
The interior of the cone is all points where $\phi<\alpha.$
(In this case $\phi$ is measured from the $z$-axis; anything else would make this
integration much harder, I think.)
It should be fairly obvious how this affects the region of integration.
The range of $\rho$ is still $0$ to $2a \sin \phi \sin \theta,$ as you previously
determined, and you can still take $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac\pi2.$
I *think* the main difference is you take $\phi$ only from $0$ to $\alpha$;
also, unless this was meant to be a double-ended cone, this integral would
cover half the volume (which is all above the $x,y$ plane along with the cone),
so you would only multiply by two rather than four.
If the cone is double-ended, however, you would still have the four-way symmetry
and would still multiply by four.

For part 3, the plot of $y^2 = x$ in the $x,y$ plane is as shown in the
figure below 
(courtesy of https://www.desmos.com/calculator, a very handy tool to remember).
The lines $x=0$ and $x=2$ are also shown; the region bounded by all these
curves should be clear enough.

[image: plot of parabola y^2=x and lines x=0 and x=2]

Comment: For P3 : I am confused whether region is going towards infinity (bouded by three of them )..or it is inbetween $y^{2}=x$ and $x=2$

Comment: For P3 : I am confused whether region is going towards infinity (bouded by three of them )..or it is inbetween $y^{2}=x$ and $x=2$              For P2 : I am able to figure out situation correctly ,are bounds of $\phi$ are 0 to $\alpha$ . For P1 : As per i have understood ,with my limits i am taking region from $y=a$ to $y=2a$ also which ain't needed.Also i havent understood how u have done by spherical around z ,but i see it becomes difficultt to handle .Can u tell me if i take spherical cord around y axis how would that situation be then . Thanks

Comment: @godonichia:I suppose the finite region is the one desired (otherwise I think the answer would be undefined). I am not entirely happy with the way the bounds are stated; I would prefer inequalities, which would tell us which side of the bound the region should be on.

Comment: pls see other comment

Comment: @godonichia: Yes, saw that and was in the process of writing something up. I added to the answer for part 2 to address that point.

Comment: I f i take my Y axis as where  i we usually take z axis then ,then by using cylindrical coordinated and in order $dxdzdy$ , y goes ffrom 0 to a . and in x-z plane i will have circle of with radius a .That would be straighforward or ordinary cylindrical integration .Am i right ?

Comment: if above is correct then i am done with P1 ,then pls tell me about P2 and lets finish this q

Comment: Yes, cylindrical coordinates for part 1 would be fine, and probably preferable to spherical. I'll add a bit for part 2, but I think you were already very close when you first asked.

Comment: How does one derive the point on the sphere being $2 a \sin \phi \sin \theta$?

Comment: Let $x^2 + (y-a)^2 + z^2 = a^2,$ substitute spherical coordinates (where $\phi$ is the angle from the $z$-axis) for $x,y,z,$ and solve for $\rho.$ This may be worth a separate question (what are spherical coordinates of a sphere tangent to the axis of the coordinate system).